# Можно ли сделать вращение при помощи hover-rotate, но так, чтобы объект вращался только в одну сторону

Tags: html, css

Хочу вращать объект при наведение на него, но когда я отвожу стрелку от объекта, то оно начинает вращаться в обратную сторону. Можно ли сделать, чтобы обратного вращения не было? Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`animation-play-state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) изначально `paused`, а при `:hover` ставите `running`

```css
.rotate {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  animation: Rotate 1s linear infinite paused;
}

.rotate:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes Rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

Comment: Блин.. Я совершенно по-другому вопрос понял...

Comment: @Qwertiy, да чёт как-то все по разному поняли :D

Answer (score 4):

У меня что-то такое получилось, но есть 2 проблемы:

1. При открытии страницы есть лишний оборот.
2. Надо держать мышь достаточно долго, чтобы анимация `hover` завершилась.

```css
div {
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, red, blue);
  animation: rotate-2 1s linear 1;
}

div:hover {
  animation-name: rotate-1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rotate-1 {
  from { transform: rotate(  0deg) }
  to   { transform: rotate(180deg) }
}

@keyframes rotate-2 {
  from { transform: rotate(180deg) }
  to   { transform: rotate(360deg) }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Первый пункт могу исправить с помощью элемента-обёртки, но при  наведении в первую секунду после открытия анимация будет глючить:

```css
section {
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rotate-1 1s linear 1 reverse;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, red, blue);
  animation: inherit;
  animation-name: rotate-2;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

div:hover {
  animation-name: rotate-1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rotate-1 {
  from { transform: rotate(  0deg) }
  to   { transform: rotate(180deg) }
}

@keyframes rotate-2 {
  from { transform: rotate(180deg) }
  to   { transform: rotate(360deg) }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

И ещё один вариант, но мышь по-прежнему надо держать над блоком до завершения первого поворота:

```css
div {
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, red, blue);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

div:hover {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  animation: rotate 1s linear 1;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(180deg); }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Или ещё проще:

```css
.rotate {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background:yellowgreen;
 
}

.rotate:hover {
   animation: move 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(720deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

Comment: А вот тут я на почти уверен, что автор хотел не это)

Comment: @Qwertiy А зачем за автора гадать? Сейчас у него в вопросе "Можно ли сделать, чтобы обратного вращения не было?" при отводе курсора. Придет и выберет ответ, судя по всему твой, как самый красивый с градиентами :) Лови плюс (+)

Comment: Вполне возможно, что автор имел в виду то, что в ответе De.Minov - тут точно не угадаешь. У тебя вообще третья интерпретация, которая самая странная))) Ладно, держи плюсик)